# Bind one texture to two different uniform samplers

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-3

Is that possible to bind one texture to two ( or more ) different uniform samplers in openGL?
When rendering with two different textures it goes like this:

Shader:

```
uniform sampler2D texture1;
uniform sampler2D texture2;
....
```

Client:

```
//Initial shader program setup.
glLinkProgram(program);

GLuint texture1Loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "texture1");
GLuint texture2Loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "texture2");

glUseProgram(program);
glUniform1i(texture1Loc, 0); //Texture unit 0 is for texture1 sampler.
glUniform1i(texture2Loc, 1); //Texture unit 1 is for texture2 sampler.

//When rendering an object with this program.
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);

//Render stuff
glDraw*();
```

But when I try to bind one texture object to two different texture units, it seems like that the unit that was binded first stays unbinded:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1); // bind texture1
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1); // bind texture1 - again, but to another unit
```

Of course it is possible to set same unit for both samplers, but from time to time I also want to use my shader for different textures - not only to set thesame texture object to both samplers.

```
glUniform1i(texture1Loc, 0); //Texture unit 0 is for texture1 sampler.
glUniform1i(texture2Loc, 0); //Texture unit 0 is for texture2 sampler ( thesame unit ).
```

This solution actualy works pretty good, but it doesn't fit me needs as described.
It is also possible to change texture unit for a sampler just before binding, but it doesn't seem to be a clean solution to me.

```
glUniform1i(texture1Loc, 0); //Texture unit 0 is for texture1 sampler.
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);


glUniform1i(texture2Loc, 1); //Texture unit 1 is for texture2 sampler
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);

....

glUniform1i(texture1Loc, 0); //Texture unit 0 is for texture1 sampler.
glUniform1i(texture2Loc, 0); //Texture unit 0 is for texture2 sampler.
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
```

Is there any solution for that? Maybe the very first approach is correct but I do something wrong? Is that possible to bind one texture to many units?

Comment: You know the section `...` in your (fragment?) shader, where the uniforms are actually used, is missing? It's difficult to diagnose your problem without seeing how the uniforms are used in the compiled and linked program. That means it's actually important that you show the rest of the shader, and because some GLSL compilers do stuff in two-passes, the other shader stages as well. If the compiler determines a codepath is dead somehow it will start removing/replacing constant expressions.

Answer (score 3):

Binding the same texture to two different texture units, and using both texture units in a shader, should be perfectly fine. There's either a different problem in your code, or a problem in the OpenGL implementation you are using.

The only somewhat related error condition I can find is the following, on page 82 of the OpenGL 3.3 spec, in the sub-section "Validation" under section "2.11 Vertex Shaders":

> This error is generated by any command that transfers vertices to the GL if: [..] any two active samplers in the current program object are of different types, but refer to the same texture image unit, [..]

But that's not what you're doing, and I've never seen anything specified that would prevent you from binding the same texture to multiple texture units. If such a restriction existed, I would expect it to be in the same section as the one quoted above, and no such thing is specified there.

Comment: Also, such a restriction would make the usage of Sampler objects pointless (same texture, bound in multiple texture units, each one with a different sampler active).

Comment: I've checked for both OpenGL and GLSL errors - there is non and it still does work as described. I can not find any information about this example both on the internet and on OGL docs. I'm using OpenGL 3.3.11672, GLSL 330, with Radeon 4650m on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Do you have another configuration you can try it on? Particularly with a GPU from a different vendor?

Comment: @Krzycho: including calling the (almost unknown) `glValidateProgram` function just before drawing anything (that is, with all the state set), and then checking the validation status and the info log?

Comment: @peppe: thnks for help, and yes - `glValidateProgram` gives me `Validation successful`.